# Read a file.img, a 3D binary volume

Tags: qt, binary, image, vtk

I have a file.img that is a 3D binary file.

I've searched and I can't find a way to render it in vtk, or open it on qt so I can then use it in vtk.

I came across this page, http://forum.codecall.net/topic/51524-reading-and-writing-files-in-c/

Comment: '3D binary file' - that could be any one of hundreds of formats, do you have any idea which one? After all `.img` files are normally associated with disc images.

Comment: Does paraview read this file?

Comment: @cmannett85 it also has `.bin`files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to this it is possible to convert .img files to .vtk

> "Second and third datasets can be downloaded from BrainWeb (http://www.bic.mni.mcgill.ca/brainweb/), which is free of charge in use for a research. "test.vtk" was converted from "brainweb.img" using a program by Erik Vidholm (http://www.cb.uu.se/~erik/vtk/rawToVTK.cpp)."

[SOURCE](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Modelling/ExtractLargestIsosurface)